# How to iterate through a document in Moongose and perform operations in it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User Schema which is as follows:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A User must have a name"],
  },
  courseTaken: [
    {
      course: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Course",
      },
      rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        default: 0,
        validate: {
          validator: function (v) {
            return Number.isInteger(v * 2);
          },
          message: "Rating can only be incremented by 0.5",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Also, I have a Course Schema

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A Course must have a name"],
    unique: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  }
});
```

Now, I have written a function which when a user updates his rating for a course. It updates his rating for the course. Also, for the course for which his rating is updated. It calculates an average rating and stores it in its rating field. I did it as follows:

```
 exports.updateRating = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const courseID = req.body.courseID;
  const rating = req.body.rating;
  const user = req.user;

  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user._id, "courseTaken.course": courseID },
    { $set: { "courseTaken.$.rating": rating } },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then((updatedUser) => {
      if (updatedUser) {
        console.log(`Done`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Not Done`);
      }
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    let totalRating = 0;
    let numOfUsers = 0;
    for await (const doc of User.find()) {
      for (let i = 0; i < doc.courseTaken.length; i++) {
        if (doc.courseTaken[i].course == courseID && doc.courseTaken[i].rating != 0) {
          totalRating += doc.courseTaken[i].rating;
          numOfUsers++;
        }
      }
    }
    let averageRating = totalRating/numOfUsers;
    console.log("Avg" + averageRating);
    Course.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: courseID },
      { $set: { rating: averageRating } },
      { new: true }
    ).then((updatedUser) => {
      if (updatedUser) {
        console.log(`Done`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Not Done`);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

But, the function is not behaving as expected for the average rating calculation. It sometimes retains the old values. Sometimes it gives unexpected results. I am not sure how to fix the errors.